# Is it possible to make option tag a link or button

Tags: jquery, django, forms, modal-dialog

I'm trying to trigger modal form using a selection from the dropdown list. In using django.

The idea is that use is filling a form. He can make a selection from the dropdown list but if he will not find a required item on the list he can add this item. He would be able to do this filling modal form.

Now it is triiger with button. The ideal situation would be if there is a button or link on the dropdown list.
Something like bootstrap offers, what is called separated link:
[image: separated link]

html - the dropdown list content

```
<option value="">---------</option>
{% for salesPersonDistributor in salesPersonsDistributor %}
<option value="{{ salesPersonDistributor.pk }}">{{ salesPersonDistributor.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

html - from template

```
<form method="post" id="subsidiaryForm"  name="text" data-subsidiaries-url="{% url 'ajax_load_subsiriaies' %}" data-salesPersonsDistributor-url="{% url 'ajax_load_salesPersonsDistributor' %}" data-salesPersonsDistributorContact-url="{% url 'ajax_load_salesPersonsDistributorContact' %}" novalidate>
        <table class="table table-borderless table-condensed">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
      <input type="hidden" name="build" value="{{ VCIUpdate }}">,
      <input id="submit" type="submit" value="save" />
      </form>

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="new_sales_person_distibutor" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="button">Dodaj przedstawiciela</button>
</div>
```

jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#new_sales_person_distibutor").modalForm({
                formURL: "{% url 'new_sales_person_distibutor' %}"
          });
   });
```

I have tried to trigger jquery usung vale if option but I have failed.

Regards
Starylass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Dropdown with < a... >

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[enter link description here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/)

Or with < select...>

```js
$('#mySelection').change(function () {
    var theChoice = $( "#mySelection option:selected" ).val()
    $( "div" ).text( theChoice ); // For explanation
    if (theChoice == "new") {
      $( "div" ).text( 'Gooooal !'); // For explanation
      // Your code here...
      }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <select class="custom-select" id="mySelection">
      <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3">------------</option>
<option value="new">Three</option>
    </select>
<div></div>
```

Good continuation...

*_Teddy_*

Comment: I used this second option. First one didn't work in my app. Thank you